# Does Apple, allow an account to push apps of similar kind, sold to multiple organisations?

Tags: ios

I have a customisable product sold to multiple organisations. The main intention of product is to grow my customer's business. Then, is it possible to push all the customised apps from a single account.

Comment: Have you read their terms of service? They don't want their store spammed with generated apps with little functionality and just different skins.

Comment: Hi, questions about App Store policies (rather than programming apps) are off topic on Stack Overflow I'm afraid.